# Avoiding isInstance statement

Tags: java, design-patterns, isinstance

How can I refactor this example to avoid these kind of situation that I need to check isInstance in every data type? Is there any pattern that I can follow?

```
public interface GenericData {}

public interface IntegerData extends GenericData{
    public Integer Data();
}

public interface StringData extends GenericData{
    public String Data();
}

public interface Client {
    public boolean LoadData(GenericData data);
}

public class IntegerClientImpl implements Client{
    public boolean LoadData(GenericData data){
        return IntegerData.class.isInstance(data);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use generics

```
public interface Client<Data extends GenericData> {
    public boolean LoadData(Data data);
}

public class IntegerClientImpl implements Client<IntegerData> {
    @Override
    public boolean LoadData(IntegerData data){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was expecting some heavy change in the code structure, but java made it easier... hehe